# Dynamically add distinctive style of id to my PageObject class

Tags: c#, selenium

I am currently using `Selenium` to write some automated tests. I am having an issue on one page where we are using `Dynamic Objects` and am having an issue with trying to store them in a `PageObject`.

I am hoping you might have some suggestions I can try.

The issue I currently have is that on the Development Forecast page we have a Grid that is dynamically created based on Number of `Plays` and then subdivided by number of `SubPlays` as attached image.

All of the Objects have a distinctive style Id such as `divPlayBar_0` for `Play1`, and `divPlayBar_1` for `Play2`,  `toggleAssetVisibility_0_`0 or `toggleAssetVisibility_0_1` for `SubPlays`, and the individual elements are `rigs_0_0_0`, `rigs_0_1_2` which are indexed by `Play#`, `SubPlay#`, and `Column#`.

I am trying to find a way to dynamically add these to my `PageObject` class. If you have any suggestions I would appreciate the help.

I am coding this in `C#` but can convert from `Java` if that is what you use.

Comment: where is your referenced image @SanjeevMenon?

Comment: My typical approach to this sort of thing would be to create new classes for the Play and SubPlay objects.  the Development Forecast page would have methods to find a specific Play, or list of existing Plays on the page, which is capable of creating instances of the Play object, which holds instances of SubPlay objects.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you not try to store them all in a page object but instead provide a method to fetch the one you want. Storing them all will not only take a lot of time to scrape the entire page for maybe only a few objects you need right now, it's more likely to cause StaleElementException errors because something in the page has changed since you fetched everything leading to you having to fetch everything again ... taking even more time. I would do something like the below.

These would all be methods inside a page object, e.g. Grid or whatever. You will likely have to tweak the names... I wasn't sure what to call them that would make sense to you given the page I can't see. :)

```
public IWebElement getPlay(String playId)
{
    return driver.FindElement(By.Id("divPlayBar_" + playId));
}
public IWebElement getSubPlay(String playId, String subPlayId)
{
    return driver.FindElement(By.Id("toggleAssetVisibility_" + playId + "_" + subPlayId));
}
public IWebElement getRig(String playId, String subPlayId, String columnNo)
{
    return driver.FindElement(By.Id("rigs_" + playId + "_" + subPlayId + "_" + columnNo));
}
```